# Ajax / PHP: Call working correctly but not alerting result from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I use the below to pass data via Ajax (in jQuery) to a PHP page. 
The PHP page then inserts them into a MySQL db (if they don't exist already).

Everything works correct but I cannot get back the result that I echo in PHP.

I thought a simple alert would do here in the success function but **I am not getting any alerts** - neither when an insert is successful nor when I intentionally submit something that already exists.

Can someone please help me with this ?

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: baseURL + "/ajax.php", // baseURL is the main URL, i.e. http://www.myurl.com
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        email: email,
        dob: dob
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$dob = $_POST["dob"]; 
$sql = "SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "record already exists";
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, dob) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $dob . "')";
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        echo 'update successful';
    }else{
        echo 'update failed';
    };
}
$conn->close();
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: If you are using chrome developer tools or firebug, please check the network log to see that the request is returned correctly. In your "Response" tab, you should be able to see this echoed message.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Chrome. Will try this.

Comment: @Timphs: I am not sure how to check this in Chrome but in IE it shows me the following: "Origin http://myurl.de not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header." + "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." -- I see all kinds of data in the network log but don't see a response there.

Comment: Are you trying to make a cross domain AJAX call, outside your current domain?

Comment: No, I don't - I have no clue why IE is showing this. I also tried adding crossDomain: true to my Ajax just in case but it doesn't change and it passes everything correctly to PHP just doesn't get anything back.

Comment: I would like to check this in Chrome as well. Where in the network log would I find the response tab there ?

Comment: Update: Chrome shows similar errors as IE (I can't find a response tab): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.myurl.de/ajax.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myurl.de' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Hmm, and by removing the baseURL and only go for the relative URL in you AJAX call, is there any difference? I might have misunderstood the error message from IE. To open the network log in chrome, just right click anywhere on the page and select the "Inspect element" option. In there, you'll have to click the "Network" tab. Now make the AJAX request, and it will show up here. Click it to get status, headers, response etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I had tried changing the URL before but that doesn't resolve it. Is there anything special I need to set on the ajax.php file ? Currently this only contains the above for testing so there is nothing else in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81134/discussion-between-timphs-and-keewee279).

Comment: This got resolved through the chat. Big Thank You to Timphs for taking the time ! I added the outcome as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the json encode solution for the response as per Ixer's suggestion which makes it easier to handle and I like the approach.

The actual issue, however, turned out to be in the baseURL that I was setting. 
I had my URL started with h`ttp:www.url...` there whereas the errors in the developer tools mentioned the URL starting with `http:url...` so for some reason it seems it considered the navigation to the ajax page as going to a different URL.

**Changing the base URL in my header to http:url... resolved the issue** - thanks to Timphs for taking the time to help me with testing this.

Answer (score 2):

return it as a JSON , using `json_encode`

```
   <?php
    //....
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        $str =  "record already exists";
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, dob) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $dob . "')";
        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
            $str = 'update successful';
        }else{
            $str = 'update failed';
        };
    }
$data = array('response' => $str);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - let me try this. Do I need to set a datatype for this in the Ajax call ?

Comment: I tried this twice but it doesn't give me any alert either (assuming I don't have to set a datatype for this in Ajax).

Comment: learn to use Firebug or Chrome developer tools. it is a bit pointless debugging like this.  You have to figure out what the server returns (whatever the message is).

Comment: Thanks - I just updated the results from this under the above comments.

Comment: We got this figured out (see comments above) but your suggestion with the json response was still very helpful. Thanks again !